# Developing an iPhone app which is friendly to blind people

Tags: iphone, accessibility, voiceover

I've had a user send me an email to ask if I can make some modifications to my application so that it is more friendly to blind people.

Although he's explained the problems that he is having, I really have no idea on how to approach this. I can't find any guidelines from Apple. Is there any information available, or does anyone have any experience with this sort of thing? Are there some simple things I can do to buttons or images to make them friendly for the blind?

Comment: Interesting: I overheard someone the other day talking about an experience their mother had, who is blind or semi-blind, where the feel of the buttons on her cell phone enabled her to find the right numbers and call for help in an emergency. They were reflecting on how it wouldn't have been possible with an iPhone.

Comment: On the flip side, I've heard from quite a few places how fantastic the iPhone is for blind users. This is a really good read: http://behindthecurtain.us/2010/06/12/my-first-week-with-the-iphone/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a WWDC 2010 video of Session 122 that covers Accessibility and how to add code to your app to help VoiceOver work better.  Should be free to view for anyone with an enrolled iOS developer account.

The easiest thing to do is to at least do a setIsAccessibilityElement and setAccessibilityLabel on all your buttons, labels and imageviews (etc.) so that they say something appropriate when a blind person wants to know what they are.

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading the [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html). It covers topics such as the VoiceOver technology that is useful for people with visual impairments or blindness, and how you can program your user interface to work with VoiceOver so that your users can "hear" your user interface.

Comment: Thanks. Accessibility was the search term I was omitting. No wonder I couldn't find anything!